# Go ssh client through Tor Network

Tags: ssh, go, tor

I've a openSSH server running on one machine which a remote machine can write files on to using a app written in go. SSH is fairly secure although I'm aware of tor ssh servers, which If I use will add extra security.

I'm confused what the scenario would be here? Is it as simple as running both machines on the tor network?

I've been reading around and saw [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.tor.user/26914) where opensshd only listens to 127.0.0.1 port 22, then having tor run a hidden service to 22 127.0.0.1:22. If I got this correctly would I just need to ssh ------.onion -l user?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You need to run ssh through a tor proxy. Unless you have a programming question, you're probably better off asking on a tor forum or maybe SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor exposes a SOCKS interface for tunneling external programs through the network. It seems like you're trying to tunnel an go program that acts as an SSH client through Tor, so you'd want to use SOCKS to proxy your SSH connection. Take a look at the [Pond](https://github.com/agl/pond/blob/25635f15df5dd5682467688e06e9f572477cad8c/client/network.go#L741) project on GitHub for an idea for handling this.